# Django 1.8 setup with mongodb

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am doing a prototype project where i have to set Django framework with MongoDB.
I am keeping my project in a virtual environment and for mangodb setup I am following below link.

http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html

But this github 
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
repository is updating my django 1.8 to django 1.5

please if any one have any idea for setup of django 1.8 to mongodb, then please help me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database is called `MongoDB`, not `MangoDB`.

Django MongoDB Engine depends on Django Nonrel which is based on Django 1.5. So you can not use the project with latest Django.

If you want to use Django 1.8, you can look at MongoEngine. But it's not very documented at this phase. Check out their examples here: https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine/blob/master/example/tumblelog/tumblelog/models.py